# Yii UrlManager GET параметр в качестве поддомена

Tags: yii, url

необходимо при вводе адреса типа

> city.domain.com/catalogue

парсить значение "city" в качестве $_GET параметра используя URL manager.

И в обратную сторону, если Yii::app()->user->getState('city') не пустой, то при переходе на страницу нужно, чтобы текущий город становился поддоменом.

Я прицепил поведение на onBeginRequest

```
class CurrentCityBehavior extends CBehavior {

public function events() {
    return array_merge(parent::events(), array(
        'onBeginRequest' => 'beginRequest',
    ));
}

public function beginRequest($event) {
    $request = new CHttpRequest;

    if ($cityName = $request->getParam('city')) {
        $cityId = Cities::model()->find('alias = :name', array(':name' => $cityName));

        if ($cityId) {
            Yii::app()->user->setState('city_id', $cityId->id);
        }

        var_dump(Yii::app()->user->getState('city_id'));
    }
}
}
```

но не могу понять как мне сдлелать так чтобы имя города вставлялось в URL.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете посмотреть в сторону [параметризации хостов](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/topics.url#sec-6)

Или можете переопределить класс CUrlManager и его методы, и там уже формировать урл и разбирать правила.

Comment: Параметризация хостов не прокатила, на счет собственного класса знаю, но всеравно не понимаю, как мне работать с этим параметром, получается, в каждом экшене нужно его принимать?

Comment: Ну есть смысл описать почему не прокатило. Класс будет запускаться при каждом запросе, он будет работать всегда, не нужно думать о экшенах и прочем.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки, буду пробовать.
Параметризация не прокатила потому, что URLManager не распознавал параметр в правиле, вываливалась ошибка...